# How do I mark the percentage change between two lines in matplotlib?

Tags: python, matplotlib, annotations

I plot two lines with matplotlib and would like to mark the maximum improvements. I use `ax.annotate` and got the following undesirable result,

[image]

Here is the source code.

```
from __future__ import division
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

fig, (ax1, ax2) = plt.subplots(1, 2)

x = range(10)
y1 = range(10)
y2 = [2*i for i in range(10)]

# plot line graphs
ax1.plot(x, y1)
ax1.plot(x, y2)

# the maximum improvements
x_max = max(x)
y1_max = max(y1)
y2_max = max(y2)
improvements = "{:.2%}".format((y2_max-y1_max)/y1_max) # percentage


ax1.annotate(improvements,
            xy=(x_max, y2_max), xycoords='data',
            xytext=(x_max, y1_max), textcoords='data', color='r',
            arrowprops=dict(arrowstyle="->", connectionstyle="arc3", color='r'))

# for showing the expected result
ax2.plot(x, y1)
ax2.plot(x, y2)

plt.show()
```

**Is there a better way to mark the percentage change between two lines?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I agree with @hobenkr. You have to split your annotation on two another annotationa: the first is an arrow and the second is a text label. For text you may set `bold` weight.

```
from __future__ import division
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

fig, (ax1, ax2) = plt.subplots(1, 2)

x = range(10)
y1 = range(10)
y2 = [2*i for i in range(10)]

# plot line graphs
ax1.plot(x, y1)
ax1.plot(x, y2)

# the maximum improvements
x_max = max(x)
y1_max = max(y1)
y2_max = max(y2)
improvements = "{:.2%}".format((y2_max-y1_max)/y1_max) # percentage

# plot arrow
ax1.annotate('',
            xy=(x_max, y2_max), xycoords='data',
            xytext=(x_max, y1_max), textcoords='data',
            arrowprops=dict(arrowstyle="->", connectionstyle="arc3",
            color='r', linewidth=3.5))

# add annotate to arrow
ax1.annotate(improvements, 
    xy=(x_max, y1_max + .3 * (y2_max-y1_max)), xycoords='data',
    xytext=(-50, 0), textcoords='offset points', color='r', weight='bold', size=10)

# for showing the expected result
ax2.plot(x, y1)
ax2.plot(x, y2)

plt.show()
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

I would split the text and the arrow into seperate pieces.

```
#!/bin/python

from __future__ import division
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

fig, (ax1, ax2) = plt.subplots(1, 2)

x = range(10)
y1 = range(10)
y2 = [2*i for i in range(10)]

# plot line graphs
ax1.plot(x, y1)
ax1.plot(x, y2)

# the maximum improvements
x_max = max(x)
y1_max = max(y1)
y2_max = max(y2)
improvements = "{:.2%}".format((y2_max-y1_max)/y1_max) # percentage

ax1.arrow(x_max, y1_max, 0, y2_max-y1_max, width=0.1, head_width=0.5, head_length=0.5, color='r', length_includes_head=True)

ax1.annotate('100.00', xy=(x_max-2, y2_max-y1_max+3), fontsize=10, color='r')

# for showing the expected result
ax2.plot(x, y1)
ax2.plot(x, y2)

plt.show()
```